# Prompt in Bash script doesn't show parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

g_yes=0
g_no=-1
g_cancel=1
g_none=127

show_yes_no_prompt()
{
        rc=$g_none
        prompt=$*
        while true; do
                read -p $prompt"(ync): "
                case $yn in
                        [Yy]* ) rc=$g_yes; break;;
                        [Nn]* ) rc=$g_no; break;;
                        [Cc]* ) rc=$g_cancel; break;;
                        * ) echo "Please answer yes/no/cancel.";;
                esac
        done
        return $rc
}

install_pkg()
{
        pkg_name=$*
        prompt="Install "$pkg_name"?"
        show_yes_no_prompt $prompt
        if [ $? -eq $g_cancel ]; then
                exit 0
        fi
        if [ $? -eq $g_yes ]; then
                apt-get install -y $pkg_name
        else
                echo "Installation of "$pkg_name" refused."     
        fi
}
```

When I write `install_pkg package1 package2` the prompt only shows *'Install'* , but I need the prompt to be like *'Install package1 package2'*. Then, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Where are you calling `install_pkg` function from ?

Comment: From the same script file.

Comment: You're using `bash`; the hashbang should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting of things is all confused. You want to quote the variable expansions.

So you want `prompt="Install $pkg_name?"` and `show_yes_no_prompt "$prompt"`, etc. instead of `prompt="Install "$pkg_name"?"` and `show_yes_no_prompt $prompt`.

What's happening here is that you are passing each word of `$prompt` as a separate argument to `show_yes_no_prompt` (which is fine-ish given that you paste them all back together with `$*` in the function, though notice that you cannot handle packages with spaces in the name correctly this way).

The problem is then when you use `$prompt` in the function you don't quote it and it gets split *again* and so `read`'s `-p` argument only sees the first word and show that's all it shows (and then gets confused by your "variable names" after that since `pkg(ync)` isn't a valid identifier.

You also don't give `yn` to read as an argument so it won't assign the value it reads to there.

A corrected version of the script is below.

```
#!/bin/sh

g_yes=0
g_no=-1
g_cancel=1
g_none=127

show_yes_no_prompt()
{
        rc=$g_none
        while true; do
                read -r -p "$* (ync): " yn
                case $yn in
                        [Yy]* ) rc=$g_yes; break;;
                        [Nn]* ) rc=$g_no; break;;
                        [Cc]* ) rc=$g_cancel; break;;
                        * ) echo "Please answer yes/no/cancel.";;
                esac
        done
        return $rc
}

install_pkg()
{
        pkgs=("$@")
        show_yes_no_prompt "Install ${pkgs[*]}?"
        if [ $? -eq $g_cancel ]; then
                exit 0
        fi
        if [ $? -eq $g_yes ]; then
                apt-get install -y "${pkgs[@]}"
        else
                echo "Installation of ${pkgs[*]} refused."     
        fi
}
```

Note how I used an array to store `$@` in the `install_pkg` function. This is the only way to handle arbitrary package names properly/safely.

The `-r` argument to `read` is almost always what you want and prevents `read` from interpreting/swallowing backslash escapes.

Also note that, in general, the `@` expansions are preferable (and should always be quoted) to the `*` expansions except when putting the expansion in a string where a single string is necessary in which case the `*` expansion is necessary).

Also note that you will never get `-1` back from a function. You'll get `255` instead.

Answer (score 1):

this is the wrong line:

```
read -p $prompt"(ync): "
```

`$prompt` contains spaces, so `read` will take only the first word of `$prompt`. The solution is, to enclose `$prompt` in `"`, so it is ensured to be a whole string.

replace it with

```
read -p "$prompt (ync): " yn
```

In general, when using `"` for strings in bash, you do can use variables directly. There is no need to split the string. If you do not want spaces, you could limit the name of the variable like this:

```
read -p "${prompt}(ync): " yn
```

Comment: I have just tried it and now prompt shows all the arguments. But now I got infinite loop!

Comment: An explanation of why would improve this answer dramatically.

Comment: @Maria_Wang yes, that is, becuase you do not declare or fill the variable `$yn`, so your case statement always fails. See my edited answer

Comment: Big thanx!! Now it works!!! But I am completely confused about which  answer I should pick as THE solution. Both were excellent!!! How Can I pick both of them?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot accept both answers. You should be able to vote up both answers though.